# For the ESPAsyncWebServer library, what are descriptive names for last two of the three send request parameters?

Tags: c++, webserver

Example1

`request->send(200, "text/plain", "Login Success!")`

Example2

```
server.on("/update", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/html", "<form method='POST' action='/update' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type='file' name='update'><input type='submit' value='Update'></form>");
  });
```

What are the names for each parameter? The first (200 in each example) is content type. What might the latter two be named?

Library: https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer

Answer (score 0):

All of it might be called the HTTP message.

The first parameter includes the status code (e.g., 200). Although, it can also include SPIFFS... so I'm not exactly sure what to call it.

It may not be actually called the content type. The second parameter might be called that. Because the third parameter is the content body. Or maybe message-body?

HTTP response descriptions might have multiple names.